# SharePoint Search to return the aspx page that embeds a PDF - NOT the PDF itself

Tags: search, pdf, pages, embedded

In a SharePoint document management solution we are working on, search is used extensively. We have a specific usecase where the content is not stored in Publishing pages but in a PDF-file which is then embedded in a page (that also displayes metadata).

The problem:
We can not get search to return the page embedding the PDF. Only the PDF itself is return.
For PDF's embedded in PowerPoints the functionality is supported (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kristopherloranger/2014/12/10/sharepoint-2013-search-enable-embedded-documents-indexing-or-a-good-reason-to-install-nov-2014-cu-1/)), but we can not find how to configure it for Publishing pages.

Thanks for helping out :-)

Comment: is it online or on prem (if latter which version)?

Comment: What do you mean by "the page embedding the PDF"?

Comment: It's in SharePoint 2013. We will port the solution to SP 2019 within a year, so if you have a solution for that version, it is also asked for.

Comment: By 'the page embedding the PDF' I mean that the PDF is displayed WITHIN a standard Publishing page (in an embed tag). This page contains metadata and additional information. The PDF must always bee read in that context.